# uploadify , insert inside .uploadifyQueueItem some html

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I'm trying to make a sistem for uploading , here is the code

```
        jQuery("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'uploader'       : domain+'/swf/uploadify.swf',
        'expressInstall': domain+"/swf/expressInstall.swf",                        
        'script'         : domain+'/upload.php',
        'cancelImg'      : domain+'/images/cancel.png',
        'buttonImg' : domain+'/images/upload_button.png',
        'width': '265',
        'height': '27',            
        'wmode': 'transparent',
        'folder'         : '/uploaded_files',
        'sizeLimit'      : 1024*1024*10,
        'scriptData': {'PHPSESSID': session_id },
        'fileExt': allowed_ext,
        'fileDesc': allowed_ext,
        'removeCompleted' : false,
        'auto'  : false,
        'multi' : false,
        'onSelect'    : function(event,ID,fileObj) {
            var type_ext=fileObj.type.substr(1);
            if(extfile[type_ext]!='undefined'){
                var url_name='<?php echo $image_dir ?>/'+extfile[type_ext]+'.png'
                console.log(url_name);
                jQuery('.uploadifyQueueItem').append('some html'); 


            }
        }
    });
```

I need to insert inside .uploadifyQueueItem image , but is not working , i think that `jQuery('.uploadifyQueueItem').append('some html');` fires before `.uploadifyQueueItem` is created , i didn't find an event that can help me to solve this problem , is possible to solve friends ? Big Thanks for Helping ,and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

At what point in the process do you need to insert inside .uploadifyQueueItem, once an item is selected?

Based on the number of events from the [uploadify docs](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/), there should be an event to handle what you need. I would suggest trying the `onSelectOnce()` event which gets fired once each time a file or group of files is added to the queue.

In addition to that, if you are trying to display the image that has been uploaded, you probably want to put that in a separate event such as [onComplete()](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/oncomplete-2/)